# In yii2 advanced template not able to create a view(companies) folder inside a module?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Actually I am new to Yii2 framework. So I was working with advance Template. I created a module. As I created a module folder inside backend and then a settings module. The problem when I a using Gii tool. So I created the Model generator. 
[image]

Model class has been created successfully in the models folder inside the settings module. Now when I jump to CRUD generator
[image]
 The Issue is CompaniesController and CompaniesSearch class is being generated successfully in the desired location. But the views is not creating inside views even after the code is generating succssfully in the CRUD. I am using ubuntu. When I am checking the permission slot then I am gettng a message like you are not owner you can't change the permission. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: open terminal and write `sudo nautilus` it will open explorer with root access and now navigate to `views` folder and set permission to `0644` then retry to generate crud

Comment: Thanks for help dear.

Comment: welcome. is it working solution?

Comment: Actually I used this terminal command but I couldn't access. Actually I don't have the sudo access but the IT team has solved the issue on their end. I couldn't check it. Thanks for your concern. Maybe I will bother you next time by asking some more problems. haha. I am newbie for Yii2.

Comment: SO is always here to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
sudo chown -R ashish:ashish your_view_path_folder
sudo chmod -R 644 your_view_path_folder
```

if you are using apache try:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data your_view_path_folder
sudo chmod -R 644 your_view_path_folder
```

Comment: Thanks for the help dear